# Downloading the file from S3 through AWS cli works, but through python SDk I receive 403 forbidden error! I am using same credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Downloading the file from S3 through AWS cli works, but through python SDk I receive 403 forbidden error! I am using the same credentials.

```
from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY = '******'
SECRET_KEY = '******'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                  region_name='eu-west-1'
                  )
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket_name = "****"
s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket_name, 's3://folder/xyz.tar.xz', 'abc.tar.xz')


  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 340, in _submit
    response = client.head_object(
  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/abh16/controldbagent/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Using same credentials downloading through AWS CLI works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume 2 things here.

1. You don't have a S3 policy blocking non aws-cli connections.
2. Your bucket and your objects(files) are completely private.

Then, according to [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file) the function works like `download_file(Bucket, Key, Filename)`

what is wrong is your `Key` parameter; drop the `s3://`

`s3.meta.client.download_file(bucket_name, 'folder/xyz.tar.xz', 'abc.tar.xz')`

Comment: Thank you. Dropping 's3://' didn't help. Regarding policy I will check with my DevOps team.

Comment: So it looked like something to do with policy permissions. I was given different pair of keys and it worked. thank you.